# CSS button:active not working

Tags: css

Maybe it's just a silly problem that I have overlooked.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3n4J/)

The button above the table and the delete button both obeyed the `box-shadow` in the `:active` clause but the one the the 5th cell doesn't.

I am using Chrome 23.

Comment: I'd say it looks like the problem is that the `active` selector doesn't work if it changes the positioning of an element. In your example, your `button.delete` is always absolutely positioned, but the other button is initially absolutely position, but would be relatively positioned with the `:active` attributes. Edit: This doesn't seem to be a problem with firefox, so it might be a chrome bug.

Comment: @Walkerneo I was on firefox 17.0

Comment: So if `:active` changes `position` then the whole thing simply don't take effect. Understood.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, All I could find about it is `User agents are not required to reflow a currently displayed document due to pseudo-class transitions. For instance, a style sheet may specify that the 'font-size' of an :active link should be larger than that of an inactive link, but since this may cause letters to change position when the reader selects the link, a UA may ignore the corresponding style rule.`.

Comment: @Walkerneo I don't think user agents do that, and shouldn't do that http://jsfiddle.net/JXZHk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want your button to be in the 5th td? If yes than remove this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3n4J/1/)

```
#table button{    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 1.5em
}
```

Or if you want your button to be right there(Outside Table), replace `#table button` with the below styles

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3n4J/5/)

```
#table button{    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

And also add this

```
#table button:active{    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
    background-image: none
}
```

> Note: You are using `position: absolute;`, be sure you've wrapped it
>   inside a position: relative; container

Comment: The positioning is okay. Pressing other buttons have the "pressing effect", but pressing that button doesn't.

Comment: @TwiNight Done, see my answer carefully, because you are using same `:active` and cuz positions are different you are getting that issue, 1 is absolute and other is relative

Comment: @TwiNight just make sure you press to the very left side on your button if you are checking it on fiddle because of the result watermark you wont be able to click, or else just paste my styles in your document and check

Comment: Upon more testing, simply adding `#table button:active{position:absolute;}` also works (http://jsfiddle.net/Q3n4J/6/). Not sure why both the buttons in the table are `position: absolute` but one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @TwiNight ofcourse it will work, using `#wrapper button:active` will target all buttons inside `#wrapper` so as your all 3 buttons are inside `#wrapper` it targets all, but 1 is positoined absolute, and hence on click, active turns relative and so you were facing that issue, ofcourse you can cut down those styles, was about to leave so didnt chopped extra properties :p

Comment: Maybe because `#table button.delete` is considered more specific than `#table button:active`. Still don't understand why different `positions` for `:active` and normal will break `box-shadow` but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @TwiNight it's very simple you are using `#wrapper button:active` which is relatively positioned and your button is absolutely positioned